# Excel Export CSV Import PHPmyAdmin

Tags: php, mysql, excel, phpmyadmin

I can do this process, but I want to change the values in excel that seperate the data and columns and lines.

At the moment each field is not contained in '' and is only seperated by a comma.

My question is. Is there a way to define these things in Excel?

Thanks

EDIT:
I mean can i define what character terminates the end of the line. Can I define that a cells contents should be between 'single quotes' all the things you can change in PHPmyAdmin on import. The reason being that PHPmyAdmin cannot tell where a cells contents or row ends at the moment.

Comment: The question is not very clear. Do you mean you are getting all the values in a single excel column? Like this: "val1,val2,val3..."?

Comment: I'm not sure what is your question. Are you unable to import in phpMyAdmin or is it the issue with Excel? Also, if your fields are separated by comma, try importing as CSV instead in phpMyAdmin. You may also like to look into `LOAD DATE INFILE` MySQL statement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I know I've had similar issues with PHPMyAdmin. The easiest thing is try other options.  One of them should work.  Here are some alternatives.

PHPMyAdmin can natively import Excel spreadsheets.  You can just save the spreadsheet.

PHPMyAdmin can natively import Excel exported CSV files.  I think you might have something set incorrectly if it is not working.  Try a different option in PHPMyAdmin.

You cannot, within Excel, customize termination characters, delimiters etc.  You can customize delimiters externally from Windows.  See here: http://www.ozgrid.com/forum/showthread.php?t=134498&page=1

Another alternative, save the CSV file from Excel. PHP has built in functions for importing/exporting CSV files. You can import CSV files in PHP. You can then output CSV using custom delimeters, etc. using the built in functions and doing what ever other manipulations you want to do.  See: http://php.net/manual/en/function.fgetcsv.php

Answer (score 1):

Use this tutorial to create a VB macro. You'll just have to modify the code to use single quotes instead of double quotes.

```
For Each CurrCell In CurrRow.Cells
  CurrTextStr = CurrTextStr & "'" & CurrCell.Value & "'" & ListSep
```

http://www.markinns.com/articles/full/export_excel_csvs_with_double_quotes